# Eclipse CDT fails to resolve most standard library constructs

Tags: eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt, indexer

I'm using Eclipse CDT Mars (and sometimes Cevelop) on Debian Stretch (and sometimes on Fedora 22), to write some C++ code. My project is properly defined, in Eclipse and it even builds when I'm temporarily out of bugs.

However...... most (or all) of the C++ standard library constructs are marked as unresolved definitions: std::string, std::make_pair, std::map, all of it. I tried to manually add any include directory I could think of, but to no avail:

```
/usr/include/
/usr/include/c++/4.9
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits
/usr/include/c++/4.9/debug
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed
```

This is not really a new problem for me, I've had this for a long while, with earlier versions of Eclipse as well, I just never got around to asking about it.

Related/similar question: [Eclipse CDT fails to resolve most standard library constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34300632/1593077) .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the use of C++11 constructs.

Eclipse runs GCC (or whatever compiler you set it up with) to parse and/or index your code. Version 4.9 of gcc, which you use, defaults to C++03 (if not earlier), and will determine C++11/C++14 syntax to be erroneous.

To change this, you'll need to modify the Indexer's GCC command-line: In the Menus, select

<kbd>Project</kbd> > <kbd>Properties</kbd> > <kbd>C/C++ General</kbd> > <kbd>Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.</kbd> > <kbd>Providers</kbd> > <kbd>CDT GCC Built-in compiler settings</kbd>

You will now see a textbox entitled "Command to get compiler specs". Add `-std=c++11` after one of the other switches.